# What does 拭いて も みて も 落ちね mean?

Tags: translation, phrases, japanese-to-english, song

This is a line from a song, and the previous one is "My reflection in a mirror so tainted I can´t see a thing"

Comment: Do you have a link to the entire lyrics, or can you give us the title?

Comment: Simply asking for a translation of a sentence is considered off-topic (See https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799). That said, if there is something in particular about the word usage or grammar that is unclear in the given context, please say so. And without context, most Japanese sentences are ambiguous, so it would be helpful if you could provide the previous sentences or a link to the whole text.